# Ad units for banners and interstitial with buildozer?

Tags: python, android, kivy, admob, buildozer

I have an apk with buildozer that works fine with test ads on an android device (my phone) in the *buildozer.spec* file   i have this line:

*android.meta_data = com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713*

the app is not published on playstore yet, and i have two types of ads banners and interstitial the question is, do i get two ad units from AdMob one for each type and if so what to do to this *android.meta_data* line ?.

On the *buildozer.spec* its said that this is a list

*# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)*

*android.meta_data = com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713*

addionally i have this line:

*android.gradle_dependencies = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'*

so m really confused of what to do exactly

Answer (score 0):

its simple u go to *android.meta_data = * line and instead of this :

*android.meta_data = com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713*

u enter this :

*android.meta_data = [com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712,com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111]*